# change a table`s status to updated on inserting new values to another table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables which are related to each other. I want to change `table 1` status to updated when I insert new values into `table 2` and return `mysqli_affected_rows()` for `table 1`

**table 1: products**

```
id    |   name
 1    |  product
```

**table 1: categories**

```
id    |   name   |  product_id
 1    |   cat 1  |      1
 2    |   cat 2  |      1
```

is this possible?!

Comment: Personally, I would suggest creating a [Stored Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html) that did both actions.  You might also look at [Triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You show the structure of the tables, but don't include any column that should be updated.  This makes me think that you don't really want an update.  You just want a query that returns whether a given product is in the categories table.

If so, the following may do what you want:

```
select p.*,
       coalesce( (select 1 from categories c where c.productid = p.id limit 1), 0) as InCategories
from products p;
```

If you try to go another route where you actually store the value in the table, you will need to use a stored procedure or triggers.  Do consider, though, what happens when you delete or update a row.  `insert` is not the only way to modify data in a table.